# How can I make my defined background fill the entire page with Bulma in Vue.js 3?

Tags: css, vuejs3, bulma

I got white background which is not the one that I defined when the content is not large enough to fill the whole screen. However, I could the see my defining background when the content cover the whole page.

I am not good at CSS so I tried to use Bulma rather than pure CSS.

I use container class as the root element as
` class="container is-fluid"

```
 ......
```

`
The see the white background when the content isn't cover the full screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao2iN.png)

I don't want that happen. I want it to take the full screen (100vh solved the less content issue but it give another problem when the content is more than the view point).

How should I solve that problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywyqo.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code in the question as text. We can't and won't try to debug screenshots. See [mcve] for more info, or the big banners that prevented you from posting this question until you abused code formatting by entering a few dots and tagging them as code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by giving min-height: 100vh to the root element. Phew

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).